# Found error while printing the ascii value of a character

Tags: c, while-loop, runtime-error, ascii

After first successful iteration, the second print statement is automatically getting printed. It is taking a whitespace its input.
Why does this happen?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main() {
        char c;
        while (1)
        {
            printf("\nEnter any character to get its ASCII value - ");
            scanf("%c",&c);
            printf("Ascii value of %c : %d",c,c);
        }
        
    }
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: 10 is the line feed that results from Enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the linefeed still remains in the input buffer, change `scanf("%c",&c);` to `scanf(" %c",&c);` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, It worked. But will you please explain to me how the linefeed is remaining in the input buffer. Because, I had even tried re-declaring the variable(char c) as null during next iteration. But I was still facing the same issue.

Comment: @SushilDikondwar Re-declaring won't work, the linefeed remains in the input buffer not in the variable `c`, so during the next iteration of the while loop, `c` reads from the input buffer which has the linefeed (`\n`) in it.